# HYG vs JNK Capital Gains

Tags: united-states, etf, capital-gains-tax, capital-gain, bond-funds

How has HYG gone years without paying a capital gains dividend, whereas JNK has paid several? I know avoiding capital gains dividends is good because it reduces the need to pay capital gains taxes, but what are the mechanics for HYG doing this?

Comment: I would change the wording to "capital gains _distribution_" instead of _dividend_. I latched on to the word _dividend_ not realizing that you were asking about _capital gains_.  There is no such thing as a "capital gain dividend".

Comment: It's possible that they aren't selling any assets and thus aren't generating any capital gains.  That would take a more thorough analysis of their holdings, though.

Comment: Right, but how does that actually work? For example, if HYG needs to sell a bond that no longer meets its requirements, what is it actually doing to get rid of it without actually selling it?

Comment: Do you know that it does? Maybe it just holds all bonds to maturity? I don't know one way or the other and can't tell from their prospectus.  If it _did_ sell assets and had a capital gain, it would be required to distribute at least part of it.  If it sells assets for a loss, there would be no gain to distribute.

Comment: Oh, I see, maybe they just hold the bonds to maturity...

Comment: Also, where do you see that JNK has paid capital gains? From [this link](https://screener.fidelity.com/ftgw/etf/goto/snapshot/distributions.jhtml?symbols=JNK) it looks like they only paid dividends as well. If you have a better source it might help answer the question.

Comment: JNK last paid a capital gains distribution in 2011. http://boxexchange.com/assets/BOXOnnMemo202645.pdf

Comment: I guess the question remains even if the bond is not sold as you said. The bond will mature. If you bought a bond at 95 and it goes to par at maturity, isn't that still a capital gain that you have to pay taxes for? Maybe HYG sells  bad securities to offset this or something.

Comment: No that would not be a capital gain.  That's a good question about offsetting gains with losses - I don't know if it's just the _net_ gains that need to be distributed.